# I try to get data com The Movie db api but this error appear: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null "

Tags: reactjs

I want to retrieve data from The Movie DB api and show only 4 movies, but for some reason it doesn't get anything.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component{

state = {
 popularMovies: null
}

async retrievePopularMovies(){
  const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=KEY_HERE';
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({popularMovies: data.results});
}
render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <h3>Popular Movies</h3>
      <div>
        {this.state.popularMovies[0].title}
      </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

It was supposed to return the title on screen for the movie with ID 0, but the only error I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

It points the problem here ->>  `{this.state.popularMovies[0].title}`

Comment: Please note, the API key is valid and i can retrieve data in browser

Comment: Are you actually executing `retrievePopularMovies` method?

Comment: with async will it not execute automaticaly?

Comment: check te URL and the method that are you making

Comment: @userct no it won't you need to run it in a method like `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of `popularMovies` is null. You should handle the initial state.
Inside `render`:

```js
if (this.state.popularMovies === null) {
  return 'Loading...'
}
```

Comment: how should i handle it?

Comment: inside `render`:

```js
if (this.state.popularMovies === null) {
  return 'Loading...'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not executing `retrievePopularMovies` method, if you execute the method you should handle the view so it doesn't try to read a null value for the initial state, it should look like this inside your `render` method

```
const movies = this.state.popularMovies ? (
  <div>
    {this.state.popularMovies[0].title}
  </div>
) : (
  <div>Loading movies...</div>
);
return (
  <div>
    <h3>Popular Movies</h3>
    <div>
      {movies}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

This will show the text "Loading movies..." while the API is called and it's executing `retrievePopularMovies` method. Once that is completed it will update the view automatically.

Comment: I tried your code and it returns this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: Then your API isn't returning the info you want, you can debug to see what it returns or add a console.log after getting the data from the API

Answer (score 0):

As @Mihályi Zoltán said, inicial value of `popularMovies` is null, and you are currently trying to access the first item of that `null` which is not possible.

A good practice is to declare, in this case `popularMovies`, as an empty list (`[]`) and then iterate over it. In this case, you are not going to be able to access the first item of that empty list, because there is no any.

You are using class based component, so take the most out of it! Use the `componentDidMount` life cycle method and make an api call in it. Then set the state as you did and the data will be available.

And, as @Pietro Nadalini suggested, make it conditionally render with a simple ternary.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mihályi Zoltán mentioned, I think you need to set the initial value of your state `popularMovies: []` instead of keeping it `null`.

Comment: i did it now, and it doesn't throw that error, but when trying to retrieve data from ID 0 it gives me a similar error

Comment: Can you make sure that you are calling the function `retrievePopularMovies`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did everything right **except call the API**.

You should add a call to function '`retrievePopularMovies`' when the component mounts.

> Also you're not keeping a track of status of API call. So when component `App` > renders for the first time, you will have 'popularMovies' from the state as null.
>   And you can't access 0th index of null.

Your code could be updated like this to just work -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    popularMovies: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.retrievePopularMovies();
  }

  async retrievePopularMovies() {
    const url =
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=651925d45022d1ae658063b443c99784";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ popularMovies: data.results });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Popular Movies</h3>
        <div>
          {!!this.state.popularMovies && this.state.popularMovies[0].title}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Notice the updates:**

1. In 'componentDidMount' lifecylce, we're calling the API to get response.
2. During render we check if we have response data available in 'popularMovies' state variable and then try to access title of 0th location data.

Comment: IT WORKED! THANKS!